# React Redux this.props always return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, undefined

I'm now at React and I'm doing some apps to study, learn more about. Aand right now I'm trying to add the logged user info to redux state, but when I try to check the value of `this.props.user` my app always returns `undefined`.

My reducer.js

```
import { LOG_USER } from '../actions/actions';

let initialState = {
  user: {
    userName: '',
    imageUrl: ''
  }
}

const userInfo = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOG_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        user: action.user
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const reducers = userInfo;

export default reducers;
```

---

My actions.js

```
export const LOG_USER = 'LOG_USER';
```

---

My SignupGoogle.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import firebase from '../../config/firebase';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { LOG_USER } from '../../actions/actions';

import './SignupGoogle.css'

class SignupGoogle extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  signup() {
    let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
      console.log('---------------------- USER before login')
      console.log(this.props.user)
      let user = {
        userName: result.user.providerData[0].displayName,
        imageUrl: result.user.providerData[0].photoURL
      }
      console.log(user)
      this.props.logUser(user)
      console.log('---------------------- USER after login')
      console.log(this.props.user)
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error.code)
      console.log(error.message)
      console.log(error.email)
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.signup} variant="contained" className="btn-google">
        Sign Up with Google
        <img className='imgGoogle' alt={"google-logo"} src={require("../../assets/img/search.png")} />
      </Button>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    user: state.user
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    logUser: (user) => dispatch({type: LOG_USER, user: user})
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignupGoogle);
```

---

And my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers/reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is what I can get at my browser log after login with Google firebase:

[image: console.log after login with Google firebase]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're `onClick` handler method is not bound to the instance of the component, modify your constructor like this and your props should no longer return `undefined`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
}
```

Alternatively you could also modify your `onClick` method to look like this:

```
<Button onClick={() => this.signup()} variant="contained" className="btn-google">
```

or turn your `onClick` handler method into an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
signup = () => {
    // ...
}
...
<Button onClick={this.signup} variant="contained" className="btn-google">
```

but the first option using `bind` is the preferred one.

Refer to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for more information on event handling.

**EDIT:**

I missed that there was another callback function involved.
You're accessing `this.props` from within another function in the `signInWithPopup`-callback. Change your callback to an arrow function, which should preserve the context of the `signup` method and fix your issue:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(result => {
    // ...
}).catch(error => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried all suggestions above but I still got undefined here ...

Comment: Your props are still undefined? That's weird.

Comment: Yes, I already followed a lot of tutorials, I think it's just some detail, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

Comment: I think you forgot to also use an arrow function in the firebase callback function

Comment: @PietroCoelho I just noticed this as well and updated my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's all about context.  Since your `signup` function is bound to the `onclick` event, the `this` context is the `<button>`.

You can either in the constructor set the `this` context:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
}
```

or use arrow syntax:

```
signup = () => {

}
```

React documentation has a good answer for event binding here:  https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score -1):

Your signup definition is fine, but you can just wrap it in an arrow function that has the proper 'this' value.

onClick={()=>signup()}